# Compile erros aftre upgrade Angular to V16 - module errors

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have updated Angular from v15 to v16 according to update.angular.io like below

```
ng update @angular/core@16 @angular/cli@16
```

I needed to updated some other packages like ag-grid to v28 and ng-select to v11.

Now when I want to build the project, I am getting errors like below:

```
 error NG8002: Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'app-my-grid'.
 error NG6002: 'SharedComponentsModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
 error NG8002: Can't bind to 'isServerModel' since it isn't a known property of 'app-my-grid'.
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-select'.
```

`app-my-grid` is component which is using `ag-grid` inside.

It seems like the ag-grid is not known and also there is no error in components.

Comment: We will need more information about app-my-grid to be able to help....